# Extradition and rendition

Tags: extradition

As a non-lawyer, I have an understanding of the terms in the subject line that comes from TV shows, stuff I heard somewhere, Facebook, etc.  And that understanding so far is this:

- Rendition is the act of one state handing someone over to another state.
- Extradition is the legal proceeding in which a court in the state where the person is found decides whether to hand them over.

Does this correspond in some way to reality?  What revisions might my understanding need?

Answer (score 2):

Rendition is the act of surrendering a person or object, generally used in the context of transfers between jurisdictions.

Rendition can also be use more broadly, in the context of producing evidence or witnesses.

Extradition is a type of rendition, relaying specifically to criminals or suspected criminals, where states have a treaty which require or allow them to do so.

Comment: If this is right, then why is it that when the suspected criminal decides not to contest the transaction, his lawyer says that he "waives extradition"?